# Enable panning functionality to orbit-controls in A-frame

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to enable the panning functionality to the orbit-controls by tizzle, without much luck.

```
<a-entity
        id="camera"
        camera
        position="0 0 12"
        orbit-controls="
            enablePan: true;
            target: #target;
            enableDamping: true;
            dampingFactor: 0.25;
            rotateSpeed:0.14;
            minDistance:3;
            maxDistance:15;"
        mouse-cursor="">
    </a-entity>
```

I want my camera to have the same functionality as the A-frame inspector camera - left-click orbit, right-click pan, inverted zoom etc. Is this possible?

See codepen - http://codepen.io/MannyMeadows/pen/XpgVEd?editors=1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Orbit Controls, the Inspector uses three.js Editor Controls: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-inspector/blob/master/src/lib/vendor/threejs/EditorControls.js

You could wrap THREE.EditorControls in a component similarly to how the Orbit Controls component wrapped the THREE.OrbitControls.

Comment: Thanks! I have aframe-orbit-controls-component working but I'd like to invert the zoom. In my industry zoom in = mouse scroll up. Is there an API property for this?